# Pandas Time difference caluclated column does not update

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

Let's use this toy data set.

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'num': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 3, 4: 3, 5: 3, 6: 3}, 
                     'date': {0: ('1995-10-03 00:00:00'), 1: ('1995-10-03 00:00:00'), 2: ('1995-10-03 00:00:00'), 3: ('1995-11-08 00:00:00'), 4: ('1995-11-08 00:00:00'), 5: ('1995-11-08 00:00:00'), 6: ('1995-11-08 00:00:00')},
                     'date2': {0: ('2011-08-30 00:00:00'), 1: ('2011-08-30 00:00:00'), 2: ('2011-08-30 00:00:00'), 3: ('2011-09-30 00:00:00'), 4: ('2011-09-30 00:00:00'), 5: ('2011-09-30 00:00:00'), 6: ('2011-09-30 00:00:00')}, 
                     'dif': {0: ('31 days 00:00:00'), 1: ('31 days 00:00:00'), 2: ('31 days 00:00:00'), 3: ('5805 days 00:00:00'), 4: ('5805 days 00:00:00'), 5: ('5805 days 00:00:00'), 6: ('5805 days 00:00:00')}} )
```

Which gives me this: (date columns need to be converted to datetime64 format)

```
   num    date        date2       dif
0   1   1995-10-03  2011-08-30  31 days
1   1   1995-10-03  2011-08-30  31 days
2   1   1995-10-03  2011-08-30  31 days
3   3   1995-11-08  2011-09-30  5805 days
4   3   1995-11-08  2011-09-30  5805 days
5   3   1995-11-08  2011-09-30  5805 days
6   3   1995-11-08  2011-09-30  5805 days
```

Let's say I update date2 column with the following code:

```
df['date2'] = np.where((df['num']==1),np.datetime64('2012-10-30'),df['date2'])
```

Now if I print the df, I see:

```
    num   date        date2       dif
0   1   1995-10-03  2012-10-30  31 days
1   1   1995-10-03  2012-10-30  31 days
2   1   1995-10-03  2012-10-30  31 days
3   3   1995-11-08  2011-09-30  5805 days
4   3   1995-11-08  2011-09-30  5805 days
5   3   1995-11-08  2011-09-30  5805 days
6   3   1995-11-08  2011-09-30  5805 days
```

`[date2]` column has been updated, but not `[dif]` column.

Note: `df['dif']= abs(df['date'] - df['date2'])`

Comment: those columns aren't magically interdependent, I think you simply need to re-run the calculation `df['dif']= abs(df['date'] - df['date2'])`

Comment: @MrFuppes your comment is the answer to my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

simply convert 'date' column and 'date2' column to Series of Datetime objects
then subtract and assign to dif column

```
df['dif'] = abs(pd.Series([np.datetime64(x) for x in df['date2']]) 
                - pd.Series([np.datetime64(x) for x in df['date']]))
```

Comment: @CoffeSyntax thanks for your answer. The question is not about how to create df['dif'], but on how to have it updated when columns involved change.

Answer (score 0):

Convert date and date2 into datetime objects, currently they are just normal objects.

Then just subtract them.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date2'])
df['dif'] = df.date2 - df.date
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. The question is not about how to create df['dif'], but on how to have it updated when columns involved change.

Comment: If you run this code everytime it changes this will work

Comment: @josepmaria how are you even detecting changes? The dataframe is stored in memory, if there’s a change you have to apply it manually or automatically with a function, meaning that when that update happens, you can run this